# Alignment of structure members and static variables

Tags: c++, visual-studio, multithreading, memory-alignment

We have some legacy code with classes that have members that are used in Interlocked* functions calls.

I want to be sure that some member variables I have are aligned on 4 byte boundaries (for use with InterlockedIncrement, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/30/222631.aspx).

I can't find anything definitive that specifies the default alignment of structure members for VS 2010.  Experimentally, I haven't been able to make a struct violate 4 byte alignment without changing the default packing.  All I have been able to find out is that the default packing is 8 bytes and that we're using that everywhere.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/30/222631.aspx

What I want to know is do we need to add __declspec(align(4)) to every variable that is used in the Interlocked* calls?

Edit:  I know about packing and how to do it.  Apologies for not being specific enough.  Will the CRT also allocate all of my structs so that, given the default packing of 8 bytes, all of my struct members will be, by default aligned on 4 byte boundaries?

Will 32 bit int static variables be aligned by default?  I'm looking for some docs on VS, but I'm having a hard time finding docs to explain the defaults.

Comment: Implicit in having a packing of 4 or 8 is that you don't need to further worry about alignment of 32-bit structure members.  That's the point of packing.

Comment: AFAIK, this doesn't help heap allocated struct members though.  Packing only lays out the members within a struct.  What if the struct starts at pointer that isn't aligned at 4 bytes?  Do I need to worry or do the VS compiler packing default and runtime behavior take care of all allocations: static, stack and heap?

Comment: The world will blow up when either the heap or the stack isn't aligning allocations.  That will happen in 2012, reportedly.

Comment: The standard makes no guarantee as to how anything will be aligned. It doesn't specify much about bits or bytes anyway. So you need to specify the alignment every time. Maybe hack up some macro to wrap it for g++ and VS. You'll never know when you are going to port.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the packing for an entire structure by using the [`#pragma pack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28VS.80%29.aspx) directive.

```
#pragma pack(4)
struct MyStruct 
{
  ...
};
#pragma pack()  // this reset the packing to default
```

Comment: One sometimes sees `#pragma pack(push,4)` and `#pragma pack(pop)` for this. This is especially useful if the current packing was not the default. I don't know if all compilers support this, though.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis Good point, using `push` and `pop` to save and restore is probably better. I'm pretty sure this is Visual Studio specific. C++0x does introduce the `alignas` keyword, once compilers implement this you'll have a portable way of specifying alignment.

Comment: Yeah, I know how to use pragmas.  I'm asking if our code I need to worry about alignment, or does the default compiler & runtime behavior take care of it?

Comment: @Tim It depends on the size of the variables being used in the Interlocked* access. As Hans Passant mentioned in a comment above, if your structure members are 32-bit, and you specify 4 or 8 byte packing for the project, you don't need to worry about it. For 64-bit members, the default 8 byte packing would suffice.

Comment: Thanks Paetorian, I do appreciate your answer.  I am concerned that Mr. Chen saw fit to warn of the danger specifically for the Interlock* functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the structure member alignment directly in your project settings. The option is called "Struct member alignment". You have just to set it to 4 bytes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh3e3fd0.aspx

> Open the **project's Property Pages** dialog box. For details, see How to: Open Project > Property Pages.
>
> Click the **C/C++** folder.
>
> Click the **Code Generation** property page.
>
> Modify the **Struct Member Alignment** property.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use __declspec(align()) as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx. You can use this with individual members of a struct. See the last example in the link above.

Comment: Except I don't need to _how_ fix alignment.  I want to know if I need to fix alignment.

Comment: I was under the impression that you had just one member variable which needed alignment, in which case the declspec(align()) example I pointed to, works. I would recommend adding declspec(align(4)) [or 8 if you are using 64bit interlocked operations] to _all_ volatile variables you are using interlocked on, just to make it explicit in the code. Hopefully, you don't have too many of them.

Comment: Also, on the question of whether alignment is required... it is required for interlocked operations because they use compiler intrinsics (which translate to specific machine op codes) which require such alignment on memory variables for the opcode to work correctly. According to msdn documentation for [InterlockedIncrement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683614(v=vs.85).aspx), if the variable is not aligned then the interlocked operation may behave unpredictably.